# Getting instance of class X from an ArrayList of class X without position

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

If I have an `ArrayList` in a Java 6 program as follows:

`ArrayList<Keyword> = new ArrayList<Keyword>();`

Where a `Keyword` has an `int keywordNo`, `String text`, `int frequency` and a few other fields.

How can I retrieve an element from the `ArrayList` if I know the `keywordText` but not the position of the element or the value of field `keywordNo`?

I know that I could use a loop and simply read through the `ArrayList` comparing `Strings` until I find the element but is there any better alternative?

Comment: Would it be possible to have more than one `Keyword` object matching a given `keywordText`?

Comment: No, they should be unique.

Comment: The `List` interface has an `indexOf()` method which returns the index of a given input Object, but it uses the `equals()` method which might not work for your case if the other fields in a `Keyword` be unknown.

Comment: I would rather avoid writing my own dedicated `equals` method for the class in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to iterate over every element in the list with a loop. For each iteration you will need to get the current element and check its value.

For faster access you should use a `Map<String, Keyword>` where the String is the keywordText.

You can put your keywords in a Map like this:

```
Map<String, Keyword> keywordsMap = new HashMap<String, Keyword>();
for (Keyword k : keywordList) {
    keywordsMap.put(k.text, k);
}
```

Then if you want to access a particular Keyword you can make a call like this:

```
Keyword result = keywordsMap.get("somekeyword");
```

Comment: And q.v. [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739192/java-method-finding-object-in-array-list-given-a-known-attribute-value) which also came to the same conclusion.

Comment: Yes, this is just what I think I will have to do.

Comment: And have a `break` statement in the loop as well.