# How can I check if an ArrayList contains an Object with a specific field value?

Tags: java, arraylist, overriding, equals, contains

I have an `ArrayList` of `Objects`.  I want to see if that `ArrayList` contains an `Object` with a particular field.

**TeamBuilder.java**

```
public class TeamBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Team team = new Team();
        team.addMember(new TeamMember("myID"));
        System.out.println(team.containsMember("myID"));  //false
    }

}
```

**TeamMember.java**

```
public class TeamMember {

    private String id;

    public TeamMember(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof TeamMember) {
            o = ((TeamMember) o).getID();
        }
        return o.equals(this.getID());
    }

}
```

**Team.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Team {

    private ArrayList<TeamMember> members = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean addMember(TeamMember teamMember) {
        if (members.contains(teamMember)) {
            return false;
        }
        members.add(teamMember);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean containsMember(String eid) {
        System.out.println(members.get(0).equals(eid));  //true
        System.out.println(members.contains(eid));  //false
        if (members.contains(eid)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I do not want to use a loop and I do not want to overwrite `arrayList.contains()`.

I was expecting `.contains()` to iterate through my list of `TeamMember`'s and return `true` when it found one that was equal to the `Object` passed.  The two `Objects` are equal, but the `.contains()` method is returning false.

How can I elegantly check to see if a `Team` contains a `TeamMember` with the specified ID?  I was under the impression I could avoid a for loop because of [Java method: Finding object in array list given a known attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739192/java-method-finding-object-in-array-list-given-a-known-attribute-value), but I am not able to get it to work.

Comment: The `String` object `myID` will never equal a `TeamMember` object with a field with some value.

Comment: Either use a loop such as a for loop , or use a HashMap, mapping your Team to its ID.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it does in my example above

Comment: Well, after you fix your broken `equals()` method in TeamMember, `System.out.println(team.containsMember( new TeamMember("myID") ));`  Don't forget to also override `hashCode()` when you override `equals()`.

Comment: Your equals method is broken. Please don't try to solve your problem by breaking this key method.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Your `TeamMember` object can be equal to a `String` object (because you've tried to hack up a solution), but a `String` object cannot be equal to a `TeamMember` object.

Comment: `ArrayList#contains` compares the specified object to the members in the list, not the other way around.

Comment: @Evorlor, just change the comparison to `return o.getID().equals(this.getID());`

Comment: @MickMnemonic What do you think that will change? Why do you think so?

Comment: He's missing the `getID()` call within `equals`. Now he's comparing a `TeamMember` with a `String`, which is why the implementation is broken.

Comment: @MickMnemonic: if he does your suggestion without first checking to see if o is a Team object, he's in for a lot of trouble. The equals method should never throw an exception. He should first check for reference equality, then class sameness, then field equality.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I think you've missed what they are trying to do. Their `equals` implementation is a hack attempt at making `List#contains` work. Your `equals` implementation suggestion won't make that work.

Comment: So what I am understanding is that my approach is awful.  Use a loop or a map.  Is that the jist of it?

Comment: Or use the list's `Stream`, with a `filter` and `findFirst`.

Comment: `"my approach is awful"` -- yes, exactly.

Comment: @Hovercraft, perhaps I wasn't clear enough: the _last statement_ should be changed per my suggestion. That would fix the implementation of `equals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant solution is to

1. First and foremost fix your equals method so that it fulfills equals contract --- meaning if `a.equals(b)` then `b.equals(a)` *must* be true.
2. You should never have a TeamMember object be equal to a String. That will result in the possibility of hard to debug side effects and bugs, that you really don't want.
3. The equals method should never throw an exception. He should first check for reference equality, then class sameness, then field equality.
4. Your TeamMember class should also override `hashCode()` and it should use the same fields as the equals method does.
5. then set up a `HashMap<String, TeamMember>` that matches ID Strings TeamMember objects.
6. Be sure that your ID's are immutable.
7. Fill your Map with String-TeamMember pairs
8. Call `get(String key)` when you need a TeamMember that matches an ID.

Comment: @MickMnemonic: yes, you are right, thanks. Corrected.